How to Refresh Identity Token Using MSAL.js When Access Token is Not Expired Yet?
I'm using NAA(Nested App Authentication) MSAL.js in my outlook desktop client to handle authentication with Azure AD, and I'm encountering an issue with refreshing the identity token.
Note: It is working fine in browser(Outlook)
Problem
When the identity token expires before the access token, I want to force MSAL.js to refresh the identity token. However, even though I pass forceRefresh: true in the acquireTokenSilent request, I keep getting the same identity token (even though it's expired), because the access token has not yet expired.

I used the forceRefresh: true option in the acquireTokenSilent method:

 const request = {
    scopes: ["openid", "profile"],
    forceRefresh: true, // Forces the token to refresh
};
msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("Identity Token: ", response.idToken);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error acquiring token: ", error);
    });


I've cleared the cache using msalInstance.clearCache() before making the request.

I've tried using acquireTokenPopup and acquireTokenRedirect as fallbacks, but I want a solution that works with acquireTokenSilent.

I checked the expiry time of the identity token using jwt-decode, and the token is indeed expired.

I also enabled verbose logging to troubleshoot but haven't found any clues on why it's failing.


What I Need Help With:

Why is the identity token not being refreshed despite using forceRefresh: true?
Is there a way to refresh the identity token separately from the access token?
Is there a known issue or workaround with MSAL.js related to this behavior?

Any help would be appreciated!
